# No gradients provided for any variable - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training an autoencoder based on the Keras framework, and I'm facing an error during the fit of the model.
I post the full code:

- Dataset:

```
train_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
valid_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

train_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
    training_path,
    class_mode = None,
    target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size = BS,
    seed = SEED,
    shuffle = 'Yes',
)

valid_gen = valid_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
    training_path,
    class_mode = None,
    target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size = BS,
    seed = SEED,
    shuffle = 'Yes',
)
```

- Model:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))

conv = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img) #256 x 256 x 32
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv) #128 x 128 x 32
conv = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool) #128 x 128 x 64
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv) #64 x 64 x 64
conv = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool) #64 x 64 x 128
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv) #32 x 32 x 128
conv = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool) #32 x 32 x 256
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv) #16 x 16 x 256
conv = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool) #16 x 16 x 512
flat = Flatten()(conv) # 16 x 16 x 512 -> 131072
encoder = Dense(units=2048, activation='relu')(flat) # 131072 -> 2048 (Bottleneck)

dense = Dense(131072, activation='relu')(encoder) 
reshape = Reshape((16, 16, 512))(dense) #16 x 16x 512
up = UpSampling2D((2,2))(reshape) #32 x 32 x 512
conv = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up) # 32 x 32 x 256
up = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv) # 64 x 64 x 256
conv = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up) # 64 x 64 x 128
up = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv) # 128 x 128 x 128
conv = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up) # 128 x 128 x 64
up = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv) # 256 x 256 x 64
decoder = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up) # 256 x 256 x 1 

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoder)
```

- Optimizer and training:

```
model_callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20),
    ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(checkpoint_path, 'autoencoder_best.h5'), monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
]

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
autoencoder.fit(train_gen, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS, validation_data=valid_gen, callbacks=model_callbacks)
```

The error message is the following:

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'conv2d_4/bias:0', 'conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'conv2d_5/bias:0', 'conv2d_6/kernel:0', 'conv2d_6/bias:0', 'conv2d_7/kernel:0', 'conv2d_7/bias:0', 'conv2d_8/kernel:0', 'conv2d_8/bias:0'].

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: the first UpSampling2D is UpSampling2D((2,2))(reshape) and not UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, but I get the same error.

Comment: Try to set `class_mode = 'binary'`. Also might not be related to error but I have never seen `shuffle = 'Yes'`

Comment: I need `class_mode = None` because autoencoder is an unsupervised learning technique; the dataset does not contain any class.

Comment: Yes I saw that a bit later, could you try to set `class_mode = 'input'`? Then every image will be identical. I suppose when you provide no labels it throws the error.

Comment: The training is started. Setting `class_mode = 'input'` seems right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose when are there no labels provided, it throws this error.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'conv2d_4/bias:0', 'conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'conv2d_5/bias:0', 'conv2d_6/kernel:0', 'conv2d_6/bias:0', 'conv2d_7/kernel:0', 'conv2d_7/bias:0', 'conv2d_8/kernel:0', 'conv2d_8/bias:0'].
```

Setting `class_mode = 'input'` has solved the problem. All classes will be identical after.